# Getting the exact x and y coordinates on react-native using react-native-pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pdf, react-native-pdf

Im trying to create a PDF viewer and modify it by inserting items(text, images) to the exact x and y coordinates on a PDF our app. Im using the react-native-pdf to view the pdf @skynetcmg47/react-native-drag-resize to drag and resize, and react-native-pdf-lib to a modify/insert text, images..
I have tried pdf-lib to modify the pdf but having issues on the release mode for android. PDFDocument.load(pdfArrayBuffer) "this.bytes.slice(start, end) undefined" and resulted to change to react-native-pdf-lib but no option to get the size of the PDF.

**Base Reference:**

https://medium.com/alameda-dev/react-native-pdf-digital-signature-b63e12cdc714

**Code:**

```
 doneSet = async (page, x, y) => {
    let newX = x;
    let newY = y;
    if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
        newX = x ? !DeviceInfo.isTablet() ? this.state.pageWidth * (x - 12) / Dimensions.get("window").width : x : 0;
        newY = y ? !DeviceInfo.isTablet() ? (this.state.pageHeight - (this.state.pageHeight * (y + 12)) / hp('90%')) :  this.state.pageHeight - y : 0;
        console.log(this.state.pageWidth, this.state.pageHeight, newX, newY, x, y, this.state.pageHeight - y)
    } else {
        newX = x ? !DeviceInfo.isTablet() ? (this.state.pageWidth  * x) / this.state.pageWidth : x : 0;
        newY = y ? !DeviceInfo.isTablet() ? (this.state.pageHeight - ((this.state.pageHeight * y) / this.state.pageHeight)) - 25 : this.state.pageHeight - y : 0;
        console.log(this.state.pageWidth, this.state.pageHeight, newX, newY, x, y)
    }
    if (this.state.pdfEditMode) {
        this.setState({ pdfEditMode: false }, () => { });
        const page1 = PDFPage
            .modify(page - 1)
            .drawImage(this.state.signaturePath, 'png', {
                x: newX, // <- X coordinate location
                y: newY, // <- Y coordinate location
                width: this.state.signatureW,
                height: this.state.signatureH
            });
        PDFDocument
            .modify(this.state.filePath)
            .modifyPages(page1)
            .write()
            .then(data => {
                RNFS.readFile(data, "base64").then((contents) => {
                    let previousDocumentCopy = this.state.previousDocument;
                    previousDocumentCopy.push({ filePath: data, pdfBase64: contents, pdfArrayBuffer: this._base64ToArrayBuffer(contents) });
                    this.setState({ filePath: data, pdfBase64: contents, pdfArrayBuffer: this._base64ToArrayBuffer(contents), documentIndex: previousDocumentCopy.length - 1, nextDocument: [], previewDocument: previousDocumentCopy, xValue: 0, yValue: 0, cxValue: 0, cyValue: 0, signatureW: 100, signatureH: 100 })
                })
            });
    }
}

render() {
   return(
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1}}>
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   {this.state.filePath ?
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <Pdf
                            minScale={1.0}
                            maxScale={1.0}
                            scale={1.0}
                            spacing={0}
                            fitPolicy={2}
                            enablePaging={true}
                            onTouchStart={(e) => {
                                console.log('touchMove', e.nativeEvent);
                                if (this.state.pdfEditMode) {
                                    this.setState({ showDraggrable: false, cxValue: e.nativeEvent.locationX, cyValue: e.nativeEvent.locationY, xValue: e.nativeEvent.locationX, yValue: e.nativeEvent.locationY }, () => {
                                        setTimeout(() => {
                                            this.setState({ showDraggrable: true, })
                                        }, 0)
                                    })
                                }
                            }}
                            usePDFKit={false}
                            source={{ uri: `data:application/pdf;base64,${this.state.pdfBase64}` }}
                            onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath, { width, height }) => { this.setPageWH(width, height) }}
                            onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages) => {
                                console.log(`current page: ${page}`);
                                this.setState({ pageNumber: page });
                            }}
                            onError={(error) => {
                                console.log(error);
                            }}
                            onPressLink={(uri) => {
                                console.log(`Link presse: ${uri}`)
                            }}
                            // onPageSingleTap={(page, x, y) => {
                            //     console.log(x, y)
                            //     this.handleSingleTap(page, x, y);
                            // }}
                            style={styles.pdf}
                        />
                       
                        {this.state.pdfEditMode && this.state.signaturePath && this.state.showDraggrable ? <DragResizeBlock isResizable isDraggable x={this.state.cxValue} y={this.state.cyValue} w={this.state.signatureW} h={this.state.signatureH}
                            onDragEnd={this._dragRelease}
                            onResize={this._resizeStart}
                            onResizeEnd={this._resizeRelease}
                            connectors={['tl', 'tr', 'br', 'bl', 'c']} >
                            <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', zIndex: 10, position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.message,]} onPress={this.removeSignature}>
                                        <Icon type={'FontAwesome5'} name={'trash'} style={{ fontSize: hp('1.8%'), margin: 3, color: '#d9534f' }} />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.message,]} onPress={() => this.doneSet(this.state.pageNumber, this.state.xValue, this.state.yValue)}>
                                        <Icon type={'FontAwesome5'} name={'check-circle'} style={{ fontSize: hp('1.8%'), margin: 3, color: '#5cb85c' }} />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                                <FastImage
                                    source={{ uri: `data:image/png;base64,${this.state.signatureBase64}` }}
                                    style={{ aspectRatio: 4 / 3, width: '100%', height: '100%', }}
                                    resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover} />
                            </View>
                        </DragResizeBlock> : null}
                    </View> : null}
</View>
</SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

**Libraries version:**

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.1",
"react-native-pdf": "^5.1.7",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
"react-native-pdf-lib": "^1.0.0",
"@skynetcmg47/react-native-drag-resize": "^1.0.3",
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit different library, I am using react-native-pdf.
and I wrapped  component with  and used `onPress` props to get current x and y.
I have to adjust detail things but this way I think you can do what you want

```
const onPress = (e) => {
console.log('onpress x: ', e.nativeEvent.locationX)
console.log('onpress y: ', e.nativeEvent.locationY)
```

}

Comment: Thank you @ykim for your answer. But i've done that and it is getting the phone/device x and y not the actual pdf x and y coordinates.

Comment: yes, I realized it later :( were you able to get pdf x and y coordinates ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. no problem... we used third party app to get the exact x and y coordinates of the fill in the pdf.

Comment: ahh I see, what did you use for the tool to get exact x,y coordinates ?

Comment: we used Skim for mac or Gimp for both mac and windows.